# pointerup event does not fire for mouse actions on a link when pointermove has been detected

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I can't get the `pointerup` event to fire on a link (an `A` tag with a `href` attribtue set) for `event.pointerType == 'mouse'` if the mouse was moved between `pointerdown` and `pointerup`.

I have the following scenario:

```js
var lastEvent = false;
var handler = function (e) {
  if (lastEvent != e.type) {
    e.target.innerHTML += e.type + ' with ' + e.pointerType + '<br/>';
    e.target.scrollTo(0, e.target.scrollHeight);
  }
  lastEvent = e.type;
}
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointerdown', handler);
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointermove', handler);
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointerup', handler);
```

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  touch-action: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

If I press a mouse button, keeps it pressed for a while and then releases it, I get this sequence:

1. pointerdown with mouse
2. pointerup with mouse

However if I press my mouse button, keeps it pressed and moves the mouse pointer around, and then releases it, I get this sequence:

1. pointerdown with mouse
2. pointermove with mouse

Problem: pointerup never fires.

I guess it is the built-in click-or-drag features in the browser (I have tested in Chrome) which blocks the `pointerup` event from firing, because If do this on a `span` or removes the `href` from the anchor link it works with this sequence:

1. pointerdown with mouse
2. pointermove with mouse
3. pointerup with mouse

Also, it works flawlessly for touch-driven `PointerEvents`:

1. pointerdown with touch
2. pointermove with touch
3. pointerup with touch

I guess there is a clever css property to set on the element to disable this `pointerup` prevention. Something like `a { pointer-actions: click; }`, but I haven't been able to find what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'oh! I stated the answer in the question, basically. It was the *drag action* which prevented the `pointerup` event from firing. Simply adding the `draggable="false"` attribute on the link element fixed this issue.

```
<a href="#" draggable="false"></a>
```

Proof of concept:

```js
var lastEvent = false;
var handler = function (e) {
  if (lastEvent != e.type) {
    e.target.innerHTML += e.type + ' with ' + e.pointerType + '<br/>';
    e.target.scrollTo(0, e.target.scrollHeight);
  }
  lastEvent = e.type;
}
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointerdown', handler);
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointermove', handler);
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('pointerup', handler);
```

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  touch-action: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" draggable="false"></a>
</div>
```

The only downside is that with `draggable` set to `false`, all `mousedown`-`mousemove`-`mouseup` will trigger a `click` event. But this can be prevented by checking if the difference for `clientX`/`clientY` between `pointerdown` and `pointerup` event is greater than a certain amount of pixels, store that in a variable and add an `click` event handler which runs `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` in this case.