# 'pointerup' event not firing on desktop, works fine on mobile

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I'm trying to come up with a cross-device code that handles pointer events.
I'm running this code successfully on Chrome/Android (using USB debugging), but the Chrome desktop just acts up and keeps firing `pointermove` after the mouse has been released.

(Another problem is that the moves are not as smooth as on the mobile)

[Playable demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rqxspz?file=index.js)

These SO posts don't solve my problem:

- [event-listener-with-pointerup-not-firing-when-activated-from-touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866776/event-listener-with-pointerup-not-firing-when-activated-from-touchscreen)
- [pointerup-event-does-not-fire-for-mouse-actions-on-a-link-when-pointermove-has-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292780/pointerup-event-does-not-fire-for-mouse-actions-on-a-link-when-pointermove-has-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pointerup" Event is assigned to the #canvas, but such event will never occur because the mouse is actually above the generated DIV circle.
Since your circles are just visual helpers, set in CSS

```css
.dot {
  /* ... */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Also, make sure to use `Event.preventDefault()` on `"pointerdown"`.

Regarding the other strategies for a seamless experience, both on desktop and on mobile (touch):

- assign only the `"pointerdown"` Event to a desired Element (`canvas` in your case)
- use the `window` object for all the other events

Edited example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

function startTouch(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const dot = document.createElement('div');
  dot.classList.add('dot');
  dot.id = ev.pointerId;
  dot.style.left = `${ev.pageX}px`;
  dot.style.top = `${ev.pageY}px`;
  dot.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${ev.pointerId * 50 % 360}, 80%, 50%)`;
  document.body.append(dot);
  canvas.setPointerCapture(ev.pointerId);
}

function moveTouch(ev) {
  const dot = document.getElementById(ev.pointerId);
  if (!dot) return;

  dot.style.left = `${ev.pageX}px`;
  dot.style.top = `${ev.pageY}px`;
}

function endTouch(ev) {
  const dot = document.getElementById(ev.pointerId);
  if (!dot) return;
  canvas.releasePointerCapture(ev.pointerId);
  removeDot(dot);
}

function removeDot(dot) {
  dot.remove();
}

canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", startTouch);
canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", moveTouch);
canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", endTouch);
canvas.addEventListener("pointercancel", endTouch);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 10vh;
}

.dot {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: deeppink;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1px);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1px);
}

#canvas {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: black;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

The code needs also this improvement:

- Don't query the DOM inside a pointermove event

### Using CSS vars

As per the comments section here's a viable solution that uses custom properties [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and JS's [CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method.
Basically the `--x` and `--y` CSS properties values are updated from the pointerdown/move event handlers to reflect the current `clientX` and `clientY` values:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

const pointersDots = (parent) => {

  const elParent = typeof parent === "string" ? el(parent) : parent;
  const dots = new Map();

  const moveDot = (elDot, {clientX: x,clientY: y}) => {
    elDot.style.setProperty("--x", x);
    elDot.style.setProperty("--y", y);
  };

  const onDown = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const elDot = elNew("div", { className: "dot" });
    elDot.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${ev.pointerId * 50 % 360}, 80%, 50%)`;
    moveDot(elDot, ev);
    elParent.append(elDot);
    dots.set(ev.pointerId, elDot);
    canvas.setPointerCapture(ev.pointerId);
  };

  const onMove = (ev) => {
    if (dots.size === 0) return;
    const elDot = dots.get(ev.pointerId);
    moveDot(elDot, ev);
  };

  const onUp = (ev) => {
    if (dots.size === 0) return;
    const elDot = dots.get(ev.pointerId);
    elDot.remove();
    dots.delete(ev.pointerId);
    canvas.releasePointerCapture(ev.pointerId);
  };

  canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", onDown);
  canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", onMove);
  canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", onUp);
  canvas.addEventListener("pointercancel", onUp);
};

// Init: Pointers helpers
pointersDots("#canvas");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.dot {
  --x: 0;
  --y: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: deeppink;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1px);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1px);
}

#canvas {
  margin: 10vh;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: black;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: not sure about the last one: `transform` keeps the element taking up its original space, and just draws it somewhere else, unlike setting top/left which actually moves the element (just use css variables instead of setting literal style values directly: `.dot { --x: 50%; --y: 50%; left: var(--x); top: var(--y); ... }` and then `element.style.setProperty('--x', whatever value you need)` on the JS side)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you're absolutely right. Removed the `transform translate` part. Thank you for the extra pair of eyes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not sure I understand your concern regarding the transform. The snippet works with it just as intended. Would that css props method improve performance?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the answer. Indeed, it was a silly mistake to listen for the other events at the target level.

Comment: Mostly: anything that's a variable should use a CSS variable. That's what they're for. You _can_ directly manipulate an element's style rules, in the same way that you _can_ use document.write, but modern JS and modern CSS and modern HTML is best written using modern JS, modern CSS, and modern HTML.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You mean JS +CSS --vars [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73058171/383904)? I'm not sure if it's wise to use `style.setProperty` for multiple pointers and pointermove [performance-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703673/383904). I'll investigate.

Comment: unless you're updating thousands of values per frame, all of which result in cascade updates, there is no point in benchmarking performance: all you care about is that it runs fast enough. Browsers are extremely good at handing CSS class and variable changes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fair enough, I gave it a go and edited. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for a nice sample! A small possible improvement might be to use setPointerCapture/releasePointerCapture instead of using window events.

Comment: **Amazing suggestion** @user1514042 . Implemented.