# JavaScript Updating CSS custom properties slower than using Element styles

Tags: css, performance, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a calendar slider for vue 3 that uses mousemove and touchmove events for the sliding animation as well as a function for doing some velocity animation. The project can be tested here: https://stackblitz.com/github/Der-Alex/vue-calendar-slider?file=src/components/VueCalendarSlider.vue

My first idea was to use a css custom property `--posx` to store the slide position with `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--posx', ${posx.value}px);`. In my style part I then set `transform: translate3d(var(--posx), 0, 0)` to move my elements. On mouseup / touchend I then used my velocity animation, so that the slider slides a bit more based on the swipe speed.

After I got everything to work, I tested the slider in a mobile chrome browser and realized that the slider stutters really bad. After some digging and fiddling around I saw, that other sliders directly write the transform property to the element via `element.style.transform = translate3d(${posx.value}px, 0, 0);`, which I then also did. After that change the slider performance is much better.

To test this behaviour you can edit the following line in the `src/components/VueCalendarSlider.vue` file: `const testCssCustomProperties = ref(false);` When set to true the css custom property is written via `document.documentElement.style.setProperty`. When set to false, `element.style.transform` is used.

After the information, that style changes could be traversed down the DOM, I set the css custom property directly at the specific element that gets transformed, but the performance keeps much worse than using style.transform.

My question now is: Can anyone explain me why `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--posx', ${posx.value}px);` performs so much worse than `element.style.transform = translate3d(${posx.value}px, 0, 0);`? I guess it has something to do with how javascript handles these parts internally and that the engine maybe moves `element.style` stuff to the gpu while `document.documentElement.style` won't be moved. But I couldn't find anything specific to that.

I hope someone can explain this to me :)

Comment: I would be interested to know this as well, as it shouldn't be the case. I personally have not noticed this being a performance issue, although it might perhaps be because you are setting this variable so high up (on the document), which means it needs to fetch its value rather high up the tree, resulting in more cycles climbing. Is applying the variable closer to the element that uses it perhaps solving some performance issues? There is just more to reevaluate when you set it higher up.

Comment: Variables in CSS are inheritable, since you set it on `:root` this will trigger a recalculation for all children (every element in the DOM in this case). In your second example, you only change the style of one DOM object, this is way less expensive than recalculating all elements.

Comment: Btw, since you use Vue 3.2 you can use [State Driven CSS](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html) for your implementation, this makes it possible to bind Vue props to your css.

Comment: @S.Visser Thanks for your reply. This sounds very logical to me. I didn't think about how css gets rendered by the browser. Of course it goes all the way down until it finds the specific element that needs to be rerendered. Also thanks for the information about State Driven CSS.

Comment: @somethinghere I guess your answer goes into the same direction. Because going deeper into the DOM tree should also have a performance improvement.

Comment: So I updated my code and set the css custom property directly at the element that receives the transformation. I have two elements so the css custom property gets written on both. It still performs worse than using style.transform. Now I am confused :D

Comment: How do you know the performance is worse? I ask that because I don't find the difference between the two versions on your demo.

Comment: @Duannx You can see it best when running the project mobile. I ran the project on my mobile phone and had a heavy stuttering animation when swiping. Maybe performance is the wrong term here... What I mean is that when using the css custom property variant, then the animation stutters really bad. I also checked the cpu time mobile in the browser dev tools and there I saw something between 40ms and 100ms for some animating frames.

Comment: @DerAlex as you're using DevTools, what does the Profiler **actually** say about the animation stutters? (I'll bet it's more to do with forced relayouts than CSS custom-properties per-se).

Answer (score 4):

**Update From 2022-09-13**

I did another performance check with the Chrome devtools and measured the following:

Picture 1 shows the performance between mousedown and mouseup for the variant where I write the new clientX position directly to the element via `element.style.transform`:

[image]

Picture 2 shows the performance for the same events. Here I write the clientX position to the CSS custom property via `element.style.setProperty('--posx', ${posx.value}px);`:

[image]

So I went a bit further and changed my code so that I directly write the CSS custom property to the element via `element.style.setProperty('--posx', ${posx.value}px);`. Same result as in picture 2.

Testing the other way around by writing the clientX position via `element.style.setProperty('transform', translate3d(${posx.value}px, 0, 0));` gives me the same result like in picture 1.

So as far as I understand, changing the CSS custom property via JavaScript forces a style recalculation for every frame, while changing the CSS property `transform: translate3d` doesn't.

So I guess that [@S.Visser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298289/s-visser) was right.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug, even if that custom CSS property isn't used anyway, it seems to cause a useless style recalculation which really harms performance when happening frequently

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Same dev-tools experience as well. What's fascinating is- I tried updating a CSS root variable that is used NOWHERE in the app, and the issue persisted. "Recalculate Style" took 200ms, "Elements Affected: 76,000". Tested Chrome and Firefox.